# Is it possible to have specific init.vim commands for different file types?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am currently using (Neo)vim to work with multiple different file types. I have an overall init.vim that works with all of them, but for certain files, like MarkDown (.md) and LaTeX, I want to add a few other remaps. For example, I want to set Neovim to record a new event in the Undo Tree after each .!?, by using . However, I only want this to apply to my Markdown and LaTeX files. Similarly, I want my .md files to have the option `set wrap` enabled and to remap `j` to `gj` and `k` to `gk`. I know how to do this in my regular config file, but is there a way to only have that configuration apply to these specific file extensions?

Comment: If you want to point to another config file at startup you can use ```vim -u ./path/to/your/vimrcfile```. If you want to load specific config files after startup you can source them. I am unsure though if either is what you mean

Comment: `init.vim` — no. File type plugins — yes. See the docs at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your commands must be local to buffer. I.e. `setlocal` instead of `set`; `nnoremap <buffer> ...` instead of simple `nnoremap ...` etc.etc.
2. Your commands must be run once, while that specific buffer is active. The cleanest way is to comply with `ftplugin`. That is, put your commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/[filetype].vim`. For example,

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim

```
setlocal wrap
nnoremap <buffer>j gj
nnoremap <buffer>k gk
```

Comment: Also note that it is likely `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` for NeoVim (see about `xdg` for more details).